# How to set default CultureInfo for float.Parse?

Tags: c#

My current CultureInfo setting is "CultureInfo("de-DE")" (by default settings), when I parse a String, it would be non-english result.

Can I set InvariantCulture default globally(init)?

```
        System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture; // not work
        CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture; // not work
        // new CultureInfo("de-DE")
        Debug.Log(float.Parse("0.11")); // 11
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do that, but I would not recommend it. It will confuse users, when they expect to enter numbers in their native format (using a "," as decimal separator for the german culture).

Instead of globally setting the culture to invariant, you should *always* use the overloads to `Parse` that take a culture as argument, explicitly specifying whether at this particular location you expect local input (the data typically comes from the UI) or invariant input (the data comes from a file or database). If you get used to this, you'll avoid a lot of culture-dependent errors.

The same applies for the related methods `ToString()` and `TryParse()`.

So, for data coming from a file use:

```
float value = float.Parse("0.11", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

or better still:

```
float value = 0;
if (!float.TryParse("0.11", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
{
    // use default value, or throw exception
}
```

If you really want to set it globally, your code appears to be correct. It works for me. To be sure, you could try:

```
var culture = new CultureInfo(...);
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = culture;
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = culture;
```

Comment: In the case, this str always comes from our config file, which is en-us surely. That's why I  need it. Show what I should do please.

Comment: @p1gd0g Updated answer. I'm actually a bit confused, because the code you show in the question works for me.

Comment: Maybe since I run it in unity? Never mind, I'll check it later.

Answer (score 0):

The parser must know which decimal separator should be used. Normally the `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` should use a `.` but..

You could pass an English culture as argument:

```
Debug.Log(float.Parse("0.11", new CultureInfo("en-US")); // 0.11
```

This won't affect the rest of the program.

Comment: Yes it works. But I mean, is there any way to set it in advance? Instead of setting CultureInfo for every float.Parse.